# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string when using Laravel DB::select

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database with a view like so

```
SurveyKey   int(11) NO          
SurveyName  varchar(255)    YES         
ContentKey  int(11) YES     0   
ContentTxt  text    YES         
ContentType_k   int(11) YES         
ContentType_v   varchar(25) NO          
Content_Active_FL   int(11) YES     1   
Content_Sort    int(11) YES         
ResponseKey int(11) YES     0   
ResponseType_k  int(11) YES         
ResponseType_v  varchar(25) NO          
ResponseTxt text    YES         
ResponseLB  float   YES         
ResponseUB  float   YES         
ResponseLB_dType    varchar(45) YES         
ResponseUB_dType    varchar(45) YES         
Response_Active_FL  int(11) YES     1   
Response_Sort   int(11) YES
```

I need to pull out each question, the responses with that particular question, and display that on a view. Here is my model:  `

```
class Survey extends Model
{


    public $qAs;


    public function setQA()
    {

        $contentKeys = DB::select("select contentkey from vw_surveycontentresponses");

        foreach ($contentKeys as $contentKey) {

            $contentTxt = DB::select("select distinct ContentTxt from vw_surveycontentresponses where contentkey=?", [$contentKey]);

            $this->qAs[$contentTxt];

            $responses=DB::Select("select ResponseTxt from vw_surveycontentresponses where contentkey=?",[$contentKey]);
            foreach ($responses as $response) {
                $this->qAs[$contentTxt][] = $response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I keep getting is

> "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

What am I missing here?

Comment: I wonder if `$contentKeys` is still an `Eloquent` statement, and not a `Collection`; could you try `$contentKeys = DB::select("select contentkey from vw_surveycontentresponses")->get();` and see if that helps? Alternatively, try doing a `dd()` or `\Log::info()` on anything to see if it is what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: `$contentKeys` is a collection of StdClass objects, so each `$contentKey` is a StdClass object, not a scalar value.... you then need to use `$contentKey->contentkey` to get the scalar value retrieved from the database from the object

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much!